# Custom Component Property to have unique value

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, custom-controls

I have implemented custom control by overriding TextBox component. it has a custom property named "DbColumn". i wanted it to act like "Name" property on TextBox, which is one Form cannot have component with same "DbColumn" value on two controls.

Is there a way to set attributes to have unique value across one Form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If runtime check is enough for you, try implementing `System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize` and add checking logic to `EndInit()`:

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox, ISupportInitialize
{
     ...
     public string DbColumn { get; set; }

     public void BeginInit() { }
     public void EndInit()
     {
         bool duplicatesFound = Parent.Controls
             .OfType<MyTextBox>()
             .GroupBy(mtb => mtb.DbColumn)
             .Any(x => x.Count() > 1);

         if (duplicatesFound)
             throw InvalidOperationException("MyTextBoxes with duplicate DbColumn property found."); 
     }
}
```

This is pretty expensive in that form, but can be easily optimized to perform the check once for every parent container, instead of `n` times (for `n` number of MyTextBoxes).

Comment: thanks for the reply. but what i need is to prevent giving same value for the DbColumn at the design time. normally user can not give same name for two components at design time. is it possible to have this attribute for my custom property.

Comment: It's not an attribute, it's designer behavior. Try putting this logic in your property's setter, that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could initialize it within the constructor with a random number or a counter. If you choose the counter, you would need to check all other objects of that class, find the largest number and use this number plus 1.